# Get Count values from 2 different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm Working with Sql Server 2008.There are 3 tables table1,table2,table3

table 1,

```
Id  Name  group  
1   ddd   a       
2   aaa   b       
3   sss   a
```

table2 Contains:

```
Id Name group
1  fff   c
2  gg    a
3  saa   b
```

table 3,

```
Id group
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

I want to get the Following Result,

```
group     count(table1)   count(table2)
a           2               1
b           1               1
c           0               1
```

What Query i can write to get Appropriate Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T3.[group],
       COUNT(T1.[group]) as Count1,
       COUNT(T2.[group]) as Count2
FROM Table3 T3 LEFT JOIN
     Table1 T1 on T3.[group]=T1.[group] LEFT JOIN
     Table2 T2 on T3.[group]=T2.[group]
GROUP BY T3.[group]
```

Result:

```
GROUP   COUNT1  COUNT2
a       2       2
b       1       1
c       0       1
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92ca5/11).

**Explanation:**

`COALESCE` will return the first parameter which is not null. So if count is null, it will return 0.

Comment: it won't work if the second table contains more than one record for one group.. check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/405ee/1

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
SELECT
   group,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE group=G.group)  AS table1count,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE group=G.group)  AS table2count
FROM table3 G
```

Comment: You don't need the `isnull()` (or even `coalesce()`).  If there are no matches, `count(*)` will return `0`.

Comment: yes. I didn't noticed that :)  corrected my answer. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into @table1 
values (1, 'aaa', 'a'),
(1, 'bbb', 'b'),
(1, 'ccc', 'c'),
(1, 'ddd', 'd')


insert into @table2 (id, name, groupcode) 
values (1, 'aaa', 'a'),
(1, 'bbb', 'b'),
(1, 'ddd', 'd')

insert into @table3 (id, name, groupcode) 
values (1, 'aaa', 'a'),
(1, 'bbb', 'b'),
(1, 'ccc', 'c'),
(1, 'ddd', 'd')

SELECT tab1.groupcode,
       COUNT(tab1.groupcode) as Count1,
       COUNT(tab2.groupcode) as Count2,
       COUNT(tab3.groupcode) as Count3
FROM @table1 tab1 
INNER JOIN @Table2 tab2 on tab1.groupcode = tab2.groupcode 
INNER JOIN @Table3 tab3 on tab1.groupcode = tab3.groupcode

/*
    USE LEFT JOINS IF YOU WANT TO RETURN ALL 
    GROUPS EVEN IF THERE IS NOT A MATCH IN
    ONE OF THE TABLES
*/


GROUP BY 
tab1.groupcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT group, T1.T1Count, T2.T2Count
FROM   Groups G
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS T1Count FROM table1 AS IT1 WHERE G.group = IT1.group) T1
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS T2Count FROM table2 AS IT2 WHERE G.group = IT2.group) T2
```